# implementing real time multiplayer game server for different mobile games

Tags: websocket, udp, real-time, multiplayer

I am trying to understand and decide upon a technology stack to implement a real time multiplayer game server for mobile games. It is not just one mobile game but any mobile game, in fact can be real time or turn-based too. I was positive to use node.js and I came across various libs for that but most of them are multi players for either a specific type of games or for one specific game.

But before I can decide on that, I was stuck in deciding the arch for such a server and especially whether to use websockets or UDP. I was going through internet and SO and understood that web sockets are encapsulations to TCP, which by itself is slower than UDP (ofcourse at the cost of reliability), but I couldnt find much info if websockets or UDP would be ideal to implement such a server?

For real time games, would both or one of them or any other protocol/standard would be ideal and fast enough syncing the game-states and communicating among the multiple players as if they were playing on the same device? How close can we imitate such a real time scenario?